# Find words in a string of text (where letters aren't consecutive)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'd like write code to find specific instances of words in a long string of text, where the letters making up the word are not adjacent, but consecutive.

The string I use will be thousands of characters long, but a as a shorter example... If I want to find instances of the word "chair" within the following string, where each letter is no more than 10 characters from the previous.

dje**c**skjwid**h**l;**a**sdjak**i**mcope**r**kldrlkadkj

To avoid the problem of finding many instances in a large string, I'd prefer to limit the distance between every two letters to 10. So the word chair in the string abc**C**abcabc**H**abc**A**abd**I**abc**R** would count. But the word chair in the string abc**C**abcabcabcabcabcabcabcab**H**jdke**A**lcnd**I**nadh**R** would not count.

Can I do this with python code? If so I'd appreciate an example that I could work with.

Maybe paste the string of text or use an input file? Have it search for the word or words I want, and then identify if those words are there?

Thanks.

Comment: do you need to check the presence of the word or obtain the indexes of letters?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with for loops and iterating all the characters in the string for each word. If it finds the first character of the word, it searches for 2nd character in the next five characters, and if it doesn't find it, it starts looking for the first character again and so on.

Comment: What have you already tried? SO is not a code-writing service, but we can help you with code you write yourself. I took a crack at it, but it got complicated fast so I'd rather see what you've tried before continuing. To start, are you aware of [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and similar functions? What about regex?

Answer (score 2):

This code below will do what you want:

```
will_find = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabcCabcabcHabcAabdIabcR"
wont_find = "abcCabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabHjdkeAlcndInadhR"
looking_for = "CHAIR"
max_look = 10

def find_word(characters, word):
    i = characters.find(word[0])

    if i == -1:
        print("I couldnt find the first character ...")
        return False

    for symbol in word:
        print(characters[i:i + max_look+1])
        if symbol in characters[i:i + max_look+1]:
            i += characters[i: i + max_look+1].find(symbol)
            print("{} is in the range of {} [{}]".format(symbol, characters[i:i+ max_look], i))
            continue
        else:
            print("Couldnt find {} in {}".format(symbol, characters[i: i + max_look]))
            return False

    return True

find_word(will_find, looking_for)
print("--------")
find_word(wont_find, looking_for)
```

Comment: Nice effort. Up-voted. But, your code doesn't start looking for C again from where it started looking for H in `abcCabcabcabcabcabCabcabcabHjdkeAlcndInadhR`

Comment: This string `abcCabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabHjdkeAlcndInadhR` is marked by the OP as invalid. So my function works just as intended. It only looks 10 characters infront of the last found character. If it finds it it shifts `looking window` by it's index.

Comment: I know how your code works. If it doesn't find the H after finding C, it should pick up from where it first found C and start looking for C again. Your code works for the strings provided by the OP, but it is not going to help him for strings with thousands of characters, which is a requirement.

Comment: I am gonna wait for the OP response and then edit it if needed. But thanks for pointing it out! :)

Comment: This code works, however it seems that if I use a string where the first target letter isn't in the first 10 characters, then it doesn't find it. So if the string is AAAAAAAAAACAHAIAR it won't find CHAIR because the first C is more than 10 characters in.

Comment: Please if the answer helped you consider giving it `+1` and the `green arrow`! :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, this may also work for you.

```
long_string = 'djecskjwidhl;asdjakimcoperkldrlkadkj'
check_word = 'chair'
def substringChecker(longString, substring):
    starting_index = []
    n , derived_word = 0, substring[0]
    for i, char in enumerate(longString[:-11]):
        if char == substring[n] and substring[n + 1] in longString[i : i + 11]:
            n += 1
            derived_word += substring[n]
            starting_index.append(i)
        if len(derived_word) == len(substring):
            return derived_word == substring, starting_index[0]
    return False
print(substringChecker(long_string, check_word))

(True, 3)
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. How can I adjust so that in addition to it printing true in the output, it also indicates locations in the string where the check word is found... Or starts? Again. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan, let me a few minutes, I will come back with a solution.

Comment: @Dan, check the update version. first letter starts at the index 3, in which the second parameter of the tuple output

Answer (score 0):

To check if the word is there:

```
string = "abccabcabchabcaabdiabcr"
word = "chair"


while string or word:
    index = string[:10].find(word[0])
    if index > -1:
        string = string[index+1:]
        word = word[1:]
        continue
    if not word:
        print("found")
    else:
        break
```